# Are two equal jQuery .on events binded twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Let's say we have a lot of to dos. We use `$('body').on('click', '.todo', do_stuff)` instead of `$('.todo').click(do_stuff)` so we'll only attach one event listener to the DOM.

However, I'm using a small MVC. Every to do view has this code `$('body').on('click', '.todo', do_stuff)`. So if we have 20 to dos, does that mean body has 20 on listeners attached or just one? will they all fire?

Comment: You can bind multiple event listeners to the same element and all of them can fire.

Comment: From your question it looks like you are trying to understand how construct $('ddd').do() works. Possibly worth reading here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Why don't you use `live` instead? `$('.todo').live('click', do_stuff)`. It will work with all current and future todo items.

Comment: `on` also works on future items as long as it's delegated

Comment: @jgauffin live has been deprecated. Plus it was slow - event delegation is much better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should kill the previous event handler:

```
<script>
    $('body').off('click','.todo', do_stuff);
    $('body').on('click', '.todo', do_stuff);
</script>
```

Including the actual event handler function in the `off()` function, will only remove that specific handler, and not all others triggered by the same elements/events. Also, avoid anonymous functions while doing this.

It's also currently suggested to abandon `unbind()` and `kill()`. `on() / off()` should suit all your event handling needs, including future live binding and deferred outcomes.

Comment: btw, I use namespacing for anon functions. 'click.yepdido'

Comment: You may also be interested in `.one()`, which unbinds itself after the first event. Several `.one()` attachments will still result in several calls to handler, so `.off()` is still needed.

Comment: You can also bind it once by flagging the body as soon as the first event handler is assigned: `$('body:not(.has-todo)').on('click', '.todo', do_stuff).addClass('has-todo')`

Answer (score 4):

If you execute that code twenty times, you'll end up with twenty event handlers bound; and yes, they will all fire.

Comment: that is a feature!
use unbind() to remove event listeners you don't need anymore

Answer (score 2):

It means that `body` has 1 listener which inspects all click events and checks the DOM structure of the event target to see if it contained a `.todo` element.

There will only ever be 1 listener on the body, regardless of how many `.todo` elements you have.

Example (rough code, ignore ready handler etc.):

```
<script>
    $('body').on('click', '.todo', myFunc); 
    // results in 1 handler on the Body, which will be called when each .todo element is clicked
</script>

<body>
    <div class="todo">Foo</div>
    <div class="todo">Bar</div>
    <div class="todo">Baz</div>
</body>
```

Comment: um, there's a contradictory answer, so a fiddle or source will be good